# A forms builder with ability to edit user responses

Tags: cms, forms, survey, crm

I'm looking for a forms builder where

1. Each user can edit their own responses any number of times
2. The user responses need to be versioned

Can anyone please suggest a forms builder or any application for that matter which does this?

Good to have features if possible:

1. The forms builder should be pretty advanced including quite a number of type of fields like file upload, conditional fields etc
2. The form building needs to be broken up into sections